# Using meta tags in nuxt 3 for social share

Tags: meta-tags, nuxt3, facebook-share

This is my facebook share button component. The meta tags and script are visible in the html but for fb share the title, description, image still not appearing. I read it might be a problem that they need to be after opening head tag, how would you be able o achieve that? Or there is an other problem?

```
<template>
  <div id="1">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div
      class="fb-share-button"
      :data-href="currentURLWithBase"
      data-layout="button"
      data-size="small"
    ></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>

const props = defineProps({
  product: Object,
  currentURLWithBase: String
})

let fbImage = computed(() => { return props.product.basic_media_list ? props.product.basic_media_list : getImageUrl('/placeholder/placeholder1.png') })

useHead({
  meta: [
    { property:"og:url", content: () => props.currentURLWithBase },
    { property:"og:type", content: "website" },
    { property:"og:title", content: () => props.product.title },
    { property:"og:description", content: () => props.product.description },
    { property:"og:image:secure", content: () => fbImage.value},
    { property:"fb:app_id", content:"MY_APP_ID" }
  ],
  script: [
    {
      hid: "fb",
      src: "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0",
      defer: true,
      onload: () => {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
      },
    },
  ]
})

</script>
```

Comment: First, because I am not sure about the specific settings of your project, I would like to remind you that the project must be SSR or SSG in order to effectively optimize SEO.

You can use Facebook's official Debug tools https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to check the problem.